# Changing the values of Model parameters

Tags: ros, gazebo-model, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi I have the following in my model plugin shown below, I was wondering how can I change the parameters of the <reset_frequency> such that it takes inputs from a ROS node which has a slider bar in it.

```
 <plugin name="particle_shooter_plugin" filename="libparticle_shooter_plugin.so">
  <reset_frequency>90.0</reset_frequency>
  <x_axis_force>-10000.0</x_axis_force>
  <y_axis_force>0</y_axis_force>
  <z_axis_force>0.0</z_axis_force>
  
  <x_origin>1.0</x_origin>
  <y_origin>0.0</y_origin>
  <z_origin>0.5</z_origin>
  
  <random_range>1</random_range>
  
</plugin>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25864/changing-the-values-of-model-parameters/) by [lucien](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26400/lucien/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Replicate the slider in your plugin. I.e. make the variable a [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) parameter.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucien](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26400/lucien/) on 2020-09-30**:
Thank You. I realize I have to do a subscriber in the plugins.
And am following this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcte5r1R7vI&t=326s